# Apache Airflow: rerun for tasks with date parameters

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have a hourly shell script job that takes a date and hour as input params. The date and hour are used to construct the input path to fetch data for the logic contained in the job DAG. When a job fails and I need to rerun it (by clicking "Clear" for the failed task node to clean up the status to re-trigger a new run), how can I make sure the date and hour used for rerun are the same as the failed run since the rerun could happen in a different hour as the original run?

Comment: How do you pass those datetime params into the DAG?

Comment: Agree with **@RyanTheCoder**, if you are (and there's no reason not to) using the `execution_date` / `ds` provided by `Airflow`'s [`context` dictionary](https://airflow.apache.org/code.html#airflow.models.BaseOperator.execute), then the re-run of `task`s triggered by deletion of `task_instance`s or `dag_run`s would automatically pick the correct `datetime` input. But be sure to clear the mist around `execution_date` (read `"Understanding the execution date"` [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/Common+Pitfalls))

Comment: Can you paste the code for your dag please? As previously mentioned you should be using airflow macros to pass in those params, if you do then when you re-run the task it'll use the same parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 options:

- Hover to the failed task which is going to clear, in its displaying tag there will be a value with key `Run:`, it is its Execution date and time.
- Click on the failed task which is going to clear, heading of its displaying popup which has the clear option will be `[taskname] on [executiondatewithtime]`
- Open the task log, the first line after the attempts count will be included a string with format `Executing <Task([TaskName]): task_id> on [ExecutionDate withTime]`